# Can't upload files in certain format - Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3, image-uploading

I created an upload form in code-igniter 3 with different directory. At first, I created upload form in format excel and PDF in each file input. But later, my boss asked me to add image/jpeg in upload form. I thought just add jpg in allowed types and add some max_size in controller will do. But files not saved in database or folder path, it only save excel and PDF format,i tried to change the user-file but no avail. No error showing so I kinda confused now. I hope you can help me with this, since i'm still learning Code-igniter.

Controller:

```
public function file_data() {        
    $this->load->view('templates/header');

    $data['program'] = $this->input->post('program');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('program', 'Program', 'trim|required');       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('file_nilai', 'File Nilai', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('file_absen', 'File Kehadiran', 'required');

    //$this->load->library('upload');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/absen';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_absen')) {      
        $this->session->set_flashdata('file_error', 'File type tidak sesuai.');
        $this->load->view('guru/upload_form', $data);

    } else {
        $upload_data_absen = $this->upload->data();
        unset($config);

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/nilai';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx|pdf|jpg|jpeg';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_nilai')) {              
            $this->session->set_flashdata('file_error', 'File type tidak sesuai.');
            $this->load->view('guru/upload_form', $data);   
        } else {
            $upload_data_nilai = $this->upload->data();

            //get the uploaded file name
            $data['file_absen'] = $upload_data_absen['file_name'];
            $data['file_nilai'] = $upload_data_nilai['file_name'];


            //store files data to the db
            $this->laporan_model->simpan_data($data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('file_success', 'Upload File Berhasil!');
            redirect(base_url() . "guru/laporan_np");

        }
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Model :

```
function simpan_data($data){        
    $data_user=$this->session->userdata('username');
    $insert_data['guru']    = $data_user;       
    $insert_data['program']    = $data['program'];       
    $insert_data['file_nilai'] = $data['file_nilai'];
    $insert_data['file_absen']   = $data['file_absen'];             

    $query = $this->db->insert('berkas', $insert_data);
}
```

View :

```html
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('guru/laporan_np/file_data');?>
    <div class="form-group">
 <label for="file_nilai">File Nilai <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file_nilai" class="form-control"  id="file_nilai" required> 
 <span><p>Allowed file types: <strong>xls, xlsx, jpeg, jpg</strong></p></span>
 <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('file_error')) { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" style="width:20%"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <?= $this->session->flashdata('file_error') ?> </div>
 <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">      
 <label for="file_absen">File Kehadiran <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file_absen" class="form-control"  id="file_absen" required> 
 <span><p>Allowed file types: <strong>pdf, jpeg, jpg</strong></p></span>
 <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('file_error')) { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" style="width:20%"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><?= $this->session->flashdata('file_error') ?> </div>
 <?php } ?>
  </div> 
  <a href="<?=base_url(). 'guru/laporan_np';?>" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;Back</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>&nbsp;Submit</button>
</form>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You must change this*

`$this->load->library('upload');`

**To**

`$this->load->library('upload',$config);`

*Maybe it creates a problem for uploading the file.*

and use one configuration.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but sadly still not working.

Comment: use this to see what is the error `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());   $this->session->set_flashdata('file_error',json_encode($error));`

Comment: Hi, @AbdulAhmad Matin i found the problems after you suggest that. I load library twice. I erased the second and add $config. Somehow it works now. Newbie mistake i hope you can forgive me..